# How to create vertices/edges/faces at the intersection of an object and a plane?

Tags: modeling, objects

I have a cubic object and a bigger plane that 'cuts' it. My objective is to create a face on the cube where the plane is cutting it without removing anything from the cube mesh, so I can't use the boolean operators. Until now, I used the Knife tool, but its accuracy leaves a lot to be desired.

I tried to use both 'Mesh > Faces > Intersect' options from the bottom dropdown menu, but neither is satisfying, Intersect Knife plainly not working and Intersect Boolean removing my entire cube.

Is there a simple solution on Blender 2.77a that involves no Python scripts and no extensions whatsoever?
Thanks in advance.[image: Picture of the plane and the mesh]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the situation? I am usure of how the plane is oriented and what is causing misfunction in the Intersect opertator.

Comment: @Carlo I added a screenshot to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are not using the **Intersect** command properly.

The intersecting plane should be inside the object to cut, so you must join the objects. You should also remember to pick only one part, and not the whole mesh in order to feed the operator with a correct source selection.

Here's two wrong sample of usage, followed by a good take.

[image]